# How should I store login details with appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have built a website that uses Facebook, Google, Yahoo, Twitter and standard email/password for account signup. It all works fine on the web but my client wants to make the website an app. I've been experimenting with using webviews with appcelerator and it looks like it will work well. The problem is the websites session will expire after 30 minutes or so. The client wants to be able to stay logged in and prevent the users from having to re-loging in all the time.

I'm thinking I need to store the login details and automatically re-login when the session has expired. Would this be the best way to handle this?

Comment: Is there an option of extending the site session to more than 30 minutes? Possibly you could track if the login information is coming from an app and make that session unexpirable

Comment: Hey asiviero. That sounds like a good idea.. and probably the simplest. I've managed to create a custom user_agent so I can identify when the website is loaded in the app and I've also worked out how to extend the session in PHP. I might set it to a month in the future so that I'm not holding on to sessions for users that aren't using the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is solved. I've going to use asiviero's suggestion.